# Why does my image drop initially when loading

Tags: html, image

I have a web page.

It has 4 img controls ina 2x2 grid.

When I load the images it initially loads like this:

[image]

The bottom left image is dropped.

It eventually loads like this after a second or so...

[image]

This is my markup:

```
  <div class="text-center vcenter" style="width: 100%;overflow:hidden ">
        <div class="container2" id="row11" style="width:360px;overflow:hidden">
            <div id="col11" class="col-xs-12">
                <div id="Live" style="width: 360px;">
                    <div class="text-center vcenter" id="row1" style="">
                        <div id="col1" class="col-xs-6" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; align-items: stretch; width: 180px;">
                            <a href="#" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;">
                                <img id="img1" alt="" class="img-responsive " />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="col2" class="col-xs-6" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; width: 180px;">
                            <a href="#" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;">
                                <img id="img2" alt="" class="img-responsive " />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center vcenter" id="row2" style="">
                        <div id="col3" class="col-xs-6" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; width: 180px;">
                            <a href="#" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;">
                                <img id="img3" alt="" class="img-responsive " />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="col4" class="col-xs-6" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; width: 180px;">
                            <a href="#" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;">
                                <img id="img4" alt="" class="img-responsive " />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

( I am using BootStrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `.row`:

```
<div class="text-center vcenter" id="row1" style="">
```

should be

```
<div class="row text-center vcenter" id="row1">
```

and, likewise

```
<div class="text-center vcenter" id="row2" style="">
```

should be

```
<div class="row text-center vcenter" id="row2">
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it's deforming the container when loading but you could try preloading them.

I normally preload using CSS like this.

```
#pre1 { background: url(Img1.jpg) no-repeat -9999px -9999px; }
#pre2 { background: url(Img2.jpg) no-repeat -9999px -9999px; }
```

Provided the paths are the same as those called in these off screen id's they'll all appear to load together.

Comment: That was useful but the other answer sorted it out - thank you

Comment: Cool glad you got it fixed :)